# Controlling one device using Alexa and Siri at the same time?

Tags: alexa, ios, apple-homekit

Can I have one device set up with HomeKit and Alexa at the same time e.g. a motion sensor, or a smart plug?

I must stress I am asking whether it is possible to set up the device with the two services **at the same time**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, providing the device provides it's own control infrastructure. The model is (roughly):

- Device connects to a gateway
- Gateway exposes an API which supports a variety of 3rd party systems
- Control messages are sent from each system which are unaware of the other systems

The exception to this model might be where a device uses one of your system hubs to provide it's connectivity. In this case, you're relying on one integrator exposing locally connected devices to a competitor.

You can refer to this [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/what-is-the-typical-network-topology-for-an-iot-network) for a general idea of how devices connect together. An endpoint may have a direct network connection (for example if it has WiFi), in which case many services can establish a connection. If the endpoint only uses bluetooth or ZigBee then some sort of hub is needed. Of course, this hub can be a device you provide if the protocols are open.

Comment: Sorry, I’m just asking for clarification: are you implying a given product must have a hub to set it up with both systems? I apologise for my ineptness - I haven’t had a smart home before

Comment: No, you don't need a hub, but the device needs to be internet connected. Added a bit to the answer to try and clarify. It's all a stack of APIs, and whilst these are authenticated, it's unlikely to be limited to 1:1 at every point.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.

As and example, I have a set of IKEA Tradfri lights that are controlled by Alexa and Google Assistant at the same time. If I had an Apple device I could add Homekit support at well.

The limiting factor is which of the systems the device manufacturer chooses to support.